# why my Mac app fails to launch, signing issue?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4

I'm developing a Mac app that will be released outside the Mac App Store.

So, basically I just automated the build process: it builds the app and signs the .app file with a Mac Dev ID.
If I sign this app with my credentials it works as expected. Either in my machine or my peers machine.
But, if my peer signs it with his credentials (using the same scripts), the app crashes either in his machine or mine. This is the error from the Console:

```
6/27/14 3:04:39.647 PM taskgated[1807]: none of the 1 applicable provisioning profile(s) apply
6/27/14 3:04:39.647 PM taskgated[1807]: killed com.myCompany.myApp[pid 2255] because its use of the com.apple.developer.team-identifier entitlement is not allowed
6/27/14 3:04:39.648 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[286]: ([0x0-0x117117].com.myCompany.myApp[2255]) Exited: Killed: 9
6/27/14 3:04:39.719 PM CoreServicesUIAgent[2258]: Error: qtn_file_apply_to_path error: Read-only file system
6/27/14 3:04:42.021 PM CoreServicesUIAgent[2258]: Unable to continue stopped application -- error -600
```

What are we doing wrong? and how can we solve it?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm having the same issue. 1 target works fine from the project the other has this issue when I want to test it on another machine.

Comment: Instead of using a Mac Developer ID, I used a "Developer ID". The later can only be created by the team agent. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html